# File not working in Lua

Tags: lua

I am doing a small program for school in Lua, but I need help. I open a file, but when I write, nothing appears in the `.txt` file. Can anyone help? This is the snippet of code I am trying to fix:

```
file=io.open('var.txt',"w+")
     io.output(file)
     io.write('hi!')
```

Edit: I tried `file:close()` and `io.flush()`, but I haven't managed to make it work.

Comment: Add `io.flush()` to the end

Comment: I believe closing the file should be enough ...

Comment: And it will be implicitly closed when the program terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
io.output('var.txt')
io.write('hi!')
io.close()
```

The function `io.output` allows you to specify a current file for output by its **filename**. In your example, you were passing a **file handler** that you created with `io.open` instead of a **filename**. This implicitly creates a bad file handler that `io.write` cannot use.

For more info, check out the chapter on ["The Simple I/O Model"](https://www.lua.org/pil/21.1.html) from ["Programming in Lua"](https://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html).